# not able to pass value to controller from routes

Tags: codeigniter-4

in Codeigneter 4 i have created a method in my controller and then added his route URL in routes.php. its working when I am not trying to receive a parameter but when I want to receive a parameter it gives the error 404 page not found.

---

My Controller Method

---

```
public function ViewProduct($param=1)
{
    echo $param;
}
```

---

my Routes.php File

---

```
$routes->get('product/(:any)', 'Public/Publiccontroller::ViewProduct/$1'); Not Working
but when I add like this its work fine 
$routes->get('product', 'Public/Publiccontroller::ViewProduct/');  Working
```

---

Answer (score 0):

look t example
query url  httpss://exmple.com/home/ViewProduct?age=35

```
public function ViewProduct($id=1)
{
   
$age=$_GET['age'];


}
```

param url httpss://exmple.com/home/ViewProduct/45454
this one receive in function

```
public function ViewProduct($id=1)
{
    echo $id;
}
```

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html?highlight=route